# multiply each cell of a data.frame with it's weight

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

What I want to do is embarrassing simple - nevertheless I fail.

I have a data.frame with "characters" and "numerics". One of the columns of the data.frame represents the weights.

I want to multiply every cell of the data frame with the corresponding weight (if it's a numeric).

How do I do that (best without using a nested loop).

Thank you in advance!

Example:

```
   c1   c2   w   
l1 abc  2    1
l2 dxf  3    0.5
l3 ghi  4    1.5
```

should become

```
   c1   c2   w   
l1 abc  2    1
l2 dxf  1.5  0.5
l3 ghi  6    1.5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a reproducible example, `dd` is a data frame with a mixture of variable types, with `W` being the weights.

```
dd <- data.frame(G=gl(2,2), X=rnorm(4), Y=1L:4L, Z=letters[1:4], W=0.3:3.3)
num.vars <- names(dd)[sapply(dd, is.numeric)]  #select numeric variables
num.vars <- setdiff(num.vars, "W")  # remove the weight variable
dd[num.vars] <- dd[num.vars] * dd$W  # multiply
```

Comment: Excellent technique for extracting numeric columns and then reinserting them. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Vectorise!

```
> dat <- data.frame(c1 = c("abc","dxf","ghi"), c2 = 2:4, w = c(1,0.5,1.5))
```

Effectively, you want `c2 * w`, but we need to tell R to look *inside* the data frame:

```
> with(dat, c2 * w)
[1] 2.0 1.5 6.0
```

Which we can insert back into `dat` in a single line:

```
> dat <- within(dat, c3 <- c2 * w)
> dat
   c1 c2   w  c3
1 abc  2 1.0 2.0
2 dxf  3 0.5 1.5
3 ghi  4 1.5 6.0
```

(Replace `c3` with `c2` if you want to overwrite the existing `c2`.)

If you have more than one numeric column other than weights, a slighlty different strategy is required if you want to automate it (i.e. not tell R which columns to multiply by `w`).

```
> ## dummy data
> dat2 <- data.frame(c1 = c("abc","dxf","ghi"), c2 = 2:4, w = c(1,0.5,1.5),
                     c3 = 5:7, c4 = 3:5)
> ## select the columns we want, all numerics, but not `w`
> want <- sapply(dat2, is.numeric) & names(dat2) != "w"
> ## then use want to index into dat2
> dat2[, want] <- with(dat2, dat2[, want] * w)
> dat2
   c1  c2   w   c3  c4
1 abc 2.0 1.0  5.0 3.0
2 dxf 1.5 0.5  3.0 2.0
3 ghi 6.0 1.5 10.5 7.5
```

Comment: thank you! I know this would work, but I have about 200 columns, therefore I can't do all those multiplikations by hand. But I guess there would be a way to do this with apply or a foreach-loop...

Comment: @Marcel I didn't notice the many columns part of the Q initially - I added an example of doing the same thing for many columns whilst you were writing your comment.

Comment: my fault - didn't mention it in my initial question

Answer (score 2):

Just for the pleasure to try to make it in one line (but really not the most readable !) :

```
R> dd <- data.frame(G=gl(2,2), X=rnorm(4), Y=1L:4L, Z=letters[1:4], W=0.3:3.3)
R> dd
  G         X Y Z   W
1 1 0.2319565 1 a 0.3
2 1 0.4242205 2 b 1.3
3 2 0.5218064 3 c 2.3
4 2 0.7155944 4 d 3.3

R> data.frame(lapply(subset(dd, select=-W), function(v, w=dd$W) { if (is.numeric(v)) v*w else v }), W=dd$W)
  G          X    Y Z   W
1 1 0.06958695  0.3 a 0.3
2 1 0.55148670  2.6 b 1.3
3 2 1.20015475  6.9 c 2.3
4 2 2.36146163 13.2 d 3.3
```

Comment: I tried it somehow like you, but I failed! I will look at this very carefully! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen, there a number of ways to do this, but somehow you'd expect one really simple way and I don't know if that exists. There is a library function in the plyr package called colwise that is close, but I can't come up with a clean way to get it to do exactly what you want. The best I can do wtih colwise is this (assuming your dataframe is named df):

w2<-df$w
df<-colwise(function(x,w){if(is.numeric(x)){x*w} else{x}})(df,df$w)
df$w<-w2

For those who are familiar with colwise, I don't think you can simply use numcolwise because then the non-numeric columns are not emitted at all. And I can't figure out any clean way to not have the multiplication appled to the weight, which is why I simply save and restore it here. I think if a cleaner way of doing this can be worked out, colwise is a nice simlpe and easy to understand way to do this.

Comment: thank you! I really thought there was a simple command that would do everything, but never mind, at least I learned something...